# Python Error ImportError: No module named skimage.io

Tags: python

When I run this program in Python, it show me this error:

```
ImportError: No module named skimage.io.
```

I have already run the command `pip install scikit-image`, but I still get this error. Can you please help me?

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.io as io
import skimage.color as color

parrots = io.imread('C:\Python27\Example\parrots.bmp')

parrots_hsv= skcolor.convert_colorspace(parrots, 'RGB','HSV')

fig, ax= plt.subplots(nclos = 2, figsize=('8,4'))
ax[0].imshow(parrots)
ax[0].set_title('original image')

restored_image =skcolore.convert_colorspace(parrots_hsv, 'HSV','RGB')
ax[1].imshow(restored_image)
ax[1].set_title('restored image')
plt.show()`enter code here`
```

Comment: Problems like this often occur because you have two Python versions on your machine, and a package has been installed into one version and then code that requires that package is being run in the other one.  This is an especially common situation when you're installing modules at the command line but running your code in an IDE.  So make sure you are installing modules into the same version of Python that you're using to run your code.

Comment: Did @Steve or I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this error like so:

```py
import math.sqrt as sq

print(sq(4))
```

Error:

```py
  File ".\Solution.py", line 1, in <module>
    import math.sqrt as sq
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math.sqrt'; 'math' is not a package
```

repaired by:

```py
from math import sqrt as sq

print(sq(4))
```

So I presume if you changed your imports to the below code it might fix it:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import io as io
from skimage import color as color
```

In addition, you might want to read a bit [here](https://medium.com/code-85/a-beginners-guide-to-importing-in-python-bb3adbbacc2b) for a simple explanation about imports.

Comment: Nice catch @Yovel!